# Spring property value is null in a specific bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Not able to read property value in a bean that is present in jar file but able to read the same property value in bean that is present in classes folder

I have a class PSContext.java which is packaged in X.jar.
I have a  bean tht is present in classes folder CFContent.java. I am able to read the property value in this file.

```
@Value("${ps.test}")
private String test;
```

But the same value I am not able to read it in PSContext.java. This bean is transient. But it should not matter I think.
Can someone let me know what is going wrong.

Regards,
JN

Comment: can you provide more details like spring configurations that would help

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 @DependsOn("ps")
 public class ..... {
   @Value("${ps.test}")
   private String test;
   ....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the bean where I was trying to get these values in not autowired. In beans where we have proper autowiring I was able to read these values